# Prestashop testimonial link

Tags: prestashop, testimonials

I'm using a theme with **testimonial slider** in homepage and I've figured out that there in the module folder a file called `all_testimonial.tpl` and something about an upload form.

So I guess that there is a way to have a page with all testimonials with the upload form.

But I'm not able to understand how could use that tpl.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

TPL file is a file extension for a template file format in general.

In Prestashop, Smarty is a template parser written in PHP

Take a have a look at these websites

- https://www.smarty.net/
- https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/smarty.for.designers

It would be difficult to answer which module for testimonial slider you are using in theme and which PrestaShop version website is using.

But I would say to have a look at the [Prestashop Hooks](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/)

To see List of Hooks -> [For a full list of Hooks](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/)

To see Module Development Changes -> https://build.prestashop.com/news/module-development-changes-in-17/